# Difficult integral for a marginal distribution

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, marginal-distribution

I am trying to derive a marginal probability distribution for $y$, and failed, having tried all methods to solve the following integral:

$$
\operatorname{p}\left(y\right) =
\int_0^{1/\sqrt{\,2\pi\,}}\!\!\!\!
\frac{\sqrt{2/\pi}\,\,\mathrm{e}^{-y/\left(2z\right)}}{\sqrt{y\, z}\,\, \sqrt{-\log \left(2\pi\,z^2\right)}}
\,\mathrm{d}z\quad \mbox{with}\quad y>0.
$$

It is easy to verify that

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-\frac{y}{2 \,z}}}{\sqrt{y\, z} \sqrt{-\log \left(2 \pi \, z^2\right)}} \, \mathrm{d}z \,\mathrm{d}y=1$$

After some work, figured out that, remarkably, we can get the fist moment, $\mathbb{E}(y)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$ and $\mathbb{E}(y^2)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2 \pi }$ without the density.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in the posting that I fixed (an extra z term). I still can't find solution.

Comment: Looks as if conditioned on the value of $Z$, $Y$ is a Gamma random variable with parameters $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{Z}}\right)$ and $Z$ had marginal pdf of the form $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log(2\pi z^2)}}$ on $(0,1/\sqrt{2\pi})$.

Comment: Indeed I am working on the product of 1) Chi-square distribution and 2) distribution of the density of a standardized Gaussian.

Comment: [Bounty: Intuition for Conditional Expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048219) (1. by linking bounty question here, this question gets attention because the bounty question is linked to this question. 2. by linking bounty question here, nero gets to see bounty question and so might answer bounty question)

Comment: I was able to simplify the integral to $$4(2\pi)^{-1/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}} \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-ze^{2t^2}\right) e^{-t^2}\,dt,$$ where $z=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}y$.

Comment: @Zachary this kind of integrals is notoriously resistant to be evaluated in closed form. I'm pretty sure there isn't much to be done here :()

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll keep trying a few methods to evaluate it, but if they don't work, this is still a rather nice form I would argue.

Comment: I find 
$$\mathbb{E}(y^n) = \frac{2^{n/2}\Gamma\Big(n+\frac12\Big)}{\pi^{(n+1)/2}\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28%282%2Fpi%29%5E%281%2F2%29*exp%28-y%2F%282z%29%29%29%2F%28-%28y*z*ln%282*pi*z%5E2%29%29%29%5E%281%2F2%29+dz) is also unable to solve it.